# Typescript `in` operator type guard narrowing only as literal

Tags: typescript, typing, typeguards

Does type narrowing with the `in` operator only work for literals or am I missing something?
Help me understand why this is happening please.

```
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    b: number;
}

// This narrows the type correctly to A
function test(arg: A | B): string {
    if ('a' in arg) {
        return arg.a;
    }
    return arg.b.toFixed(2);
}

// This doesn't
function test2(arg: A | B): string {
    let a = 'a';
    if (a in arg) {
        return arg.a;
    }
    return arg.b.toFixed(2);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Regarding to docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator)

> For a n in x expression, where n is a string literal or string literal type and x is a union type, the “true” branch narrows to types which have an optional or required property n, and the “false” branch narrows to types which have an optional or missing property n.

So, I'd willing to bet it works only with literals

**Workarounds**

```js
interface A {
    a: string;
}

interface B {
    b: number;
}

// This narrows the type correctly to A
function test(arg: A | B): string {
    if ('a' in arg) {
        return arg.a;
    }
    return arg.b.toFixed(2);
}

const isIn = <T, Prop extends string>(obj: T, prop: Prop): obj is T & Record<Prop, unknown> => prop in obj
const isIn2 = <T, Prop extends string>(obj: T, prop: Prop): obj is T & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)

// This doesn't
function test2(arg: A | B): string {
    const a: 'a' = 'a' as 'a';
    if (isIn(arg, a) /** OR isIn2(arg, a) */) {
        return arg.a; // A        
    }


    return arg.b.toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: but `a` is a string literal type, isn't it?

Comment: Looks like, they just don't support it yes. But then the docs are wrong or it's a bug: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284

Comment: I think the docs are not full yet. I know they are working hard on docs, the page I provided seems deprecated. Also there is no new page for `in` typeguard, hence - hard to tell. From time to time I'm using infromation from deprecated pages because there is no other)

Comment: `const a: 'a' = 'a' as 'a';` Can be written as:  `const a = 'a' as const;`

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

This is my improved solution

```
// This is an object as const so DataUuid is a string union
type DataUuid = keyof typeof peripheralsValueUuidNameMap

// And I used it here as well because they are all the same strings
type ServCharMap = {
  [key in DataUuid]: ServChar
}

if (characteristic.uuid in servCharMap) {
  // So now we only have the external data as a forced type.
  // Still surprised this is not inferred.
  const dataUuid = characteristic.uuid as DataUuid

  const charData = servCharMap[dataUuid]

  if (charData.bytes === 2) {
    // We can now lose this `in` check
    const name = peripheralsValueUuidNameMap[dataUuid]

  ...

  }
}
```

### See below for my reasoning

Yes I agree this is strange. I have the following code:

```
let name = ''

if (characteristic.uuid in peripheralsValueUuidNameMap) {
  const uuid =
    characteristic.uuid as keyof typeof peripheralsValueUuidNameMap

  name = peripheralsValueUuidNameMap[uuid]
}
```

I woud assume ts infers the `as keyof typeof peripheralsValueUuidNameMap` but it only stops complaining if I force it in this way.

I KNOW `characteristic.uuid` is a key of `peripheralsValueUuidNameMap` because the `in` check succeeded.

`peripheralsValueUuidNameMap` is a const type so everything about it is known.
The problem is, all keys are `const` strings so can not be indexed by `string` type. Strangely, even if the `in` check has completed. I would assume the type of `characteristic.uuid` to become a union of all key strings of `peripheralsValueUuidNameMap` and that is exactly what `as keyof typeof` does.

In this case it does work:

```
if (characteristic.uuid in servCharMap) {
  const charData = servCharMap[characteristic.uuid]
}
```

Because servCharMap has type

```
type ServCharMap = {
  [key: string]: ServChar
}
```

But here we don't even need the `in` check, `const charData = servCharMap[characteristic.uuid]` this code alone does not give a type error because we are indexing `servCharMap` with a string type. This means for all TS cares `charData` can evaluate to undefined.

`characteristic` can not be typed as a `const` type because it comes from an external data source.

So in conclusion, both situations have flaws and hide footguns.