# How can I index into an object type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

My application receives "messages". I first validate an unknown input to ensure it follows the expected message format:

```
const isMessage = x => 
  typeof x === 'object' && 
  x !== null && 
  typeof x['data'] === 'string';
```

I wish to type this in TypeScript. Here's what I have:

```
type Message = { data: string };

const isMessage = (x: unknown): x is Message => 
  typeof x === 'object' && 
  x !== null && 
  typeof x['data'] === 'string';
```

However, this fails to type-check, because:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"data"' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

After the type guard `typeof x === 'object' && x !== null`, TypeScript gives the typing `x : object`. This seems to be the same as `x : {}`. But this type does not allow me to check any properties on the object.

Instead of `x: object`, I think I want a "dictionary" type like `x: { [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown }`. But this is not the typing that TypeScript gives me from the type guard `typeof x === 'object'`.

I can use `as` to cast `x` to a dictionary type:

```
const isMessage = (x: unknown): x is Message => 
  typeof x === 'object' && 
  x !== null && 
  typeof (x as { [key: string | number | symbol]: unknown })['data'] === 'string';
```

This type-checks, but it's really long and unwieldy, and I'm not sure the `as` typecast is really type-safe.

I read about the [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing), and based on this, I expected that adding `'data' in x` would work:

```
const isMessage = (x: unknown): x is Message => 
  typeof x === 'object' && 
  x !== null && 
  'data' in x &&
  typeof x['data'] === 'string';
```

However, this makes no difference; TypeScript still complains that I can't index into `x`, even at a point where `'data' in x`. Why does this `in` operator not allow me to index into `x`?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
type Message = { data: string };

const isMessage = (x: unknown): x is Message => 
  typeof x === 'object' && 
  x !== null && 
  typeof (x as Message).data === 'string';
```

This technique is shown in TypeScript's docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

---

Since `typeof` is also a **runtime** check, the `as` assertion does not remove any type safetyness.

You can think of it this way: Before the last line, we have already checked that `x` is an object and is not `null`. So, `x.data` cannot fail at runtime, even if `x` would be `{}` or `{bar: 'bar'}` or `{data: null}`. We just need to use the assertion to make the compiler allow us to do the runtime `typeof` check.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to type-check. Although it feels like cheating - I'm casting `x` to the `Message` type _before_ I really know that it fits that type!

Comment: (In other words, TypeScript would be justified to say, "this `typeof` check is useless, because we already know `typeof x.data === 'string'`, because `x : Message`")

Comment: @jameshfisher Added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks - I can certainly see that the _runtime_ behavior is correct. I still think the `as` operator removes type safety though. [The docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) say "TypeScript only allows type assertions which convert to a **more specific** or less specific version of a type" (emphasis mine). That is, `as` is inherently unsafe. For example, `x as Message` is certainly unsafe, because at that point, we only have `x : object`. Ideally, I'm looking for a method that entirely avoids using `as`.

Comment: (Or another way of saying it - using `x as any` would be just as type-safe as `x as Message`)

Comment: @jameshfisher, this is a run-time check, so you can't rely on TypeScript "type safety", and yes `x as any` is just as good -- it lets the code compile and that's all. In the end it all boils down to `typeof`, which is a JavaScript run-time operator.

Comment: Personally, I treat `any` in the same way as `unsafe` in `Rust`. In some cases it is safe to use `any` but the more `any` you have - the more unsafe your code is

Comment: @jameshfisher This is the canonical way to do it, as per the docs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generic `hasProperty` helper for property check:

```js
type Message = { data: string };

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const isMessage = (x: unknown): x is Message =>
    typeof x === 'object' &&
    x !== null &&
    hasProperty(x, 'data') &&
    typeof x['data'] === 'string'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKATJwSAXFPMAE4CWAdilAL4DcAUMwMYD21ZUAFkvAAK5DpHKgomADwB5AEYArADRRhoqBAAewCNVzxSFGigB8ACg6KS85VDAiwJNWACUzKB6glLCqJQM2UABkUABKEJzkuFLOKgCu1ADW1BwA7tQmkibunjYRwAB09hzAJeAQBfzwMunOEOIgBWxIADYtFooqxa4s7Fw8-nCIqBhQZpokCclp1C4kmn4GQ8hoWTkeoJAcAGZQC+gHUADkPvlHwUHre1AAhIfUcW0XV1V1DeMqR-iERy7PnlBNhAdnsANpfAhII4AXUkhyOZCotCOzCAA)

Please see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382960/typescript-in-operator-type-guard-narrowing-only-as-literal) for more context about `in` operator and this [issue/43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284)

Comment: That's pretty interesting. It feels like `'data' in x` should work in a similar way, adding `& { data: unknown }` to the type of `x`

Comment: @jameshfisher I made an update regarding using `in` operator

Comment: Here `isMessage` is using only run-time checks, so it doesn't feel like "cheating"