# soft type checking function parameters

Tags: typescript, subtyping

Is it possible to tell TypeScript that the type of the value passed to a function must **possibly** match a specific type, but can also be anything else, as long as it **possibly** matches the specified type. The function would then do further verification on this own.

Here's an example:

```
function isA(value: Possibly<"A">){ //note that I completely made up the "Possibly<>" thing
    return value === "A"
}

const x: "A"|"B" = "B"
isA(x) // should work, because x could be "A"

const y: "B"|"C" = "B";
isA(y) // should be rejected by the compiler, because there's no way for y to be "A"
```

Why do I need this?
Well, if i write the function like this:

```
function isA(value: "A"){
    return value === "A"
}
```

Then I can only pass values to `isA` that are guaranteed to be "A", so there's no point in checking it.

And if I write it the following way:

```
function isA(value: string){
    return value === "A"
}
const y: "B"|"C" = "B";
isA(y)
```

Then the compiler does not complain, even though it's already clear at compile time, that it won't ever match.

I've made these examples as simple as possible on purpose. In practice I'd need it for much more complex, nested types.

Here's an example:

```
type A = {
    one: number;
    two: number;
}

function isA(value: Possibly<A>){
    return typeof value == "object" && "one" in value && "two" in value && typeof value.one === "number" && typeof value.two == "number";
}

isA({}) // should not work
isA({} as {one?: number; two?: number}) // should work
isA(undefined) // should not work
isA(undefined as undefined | A) // should work
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

**NAЇVE EXAMPLE**

```js
const isA = <A extends string>(value: 'A' extends A ? A : never) => value === "A"

declare var x: 'A' | 'B'

isA(x) // ok

declare var y: "B" | "C"

isA(y) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAgjAvDAPMgpgDylsAEwhmgCc4wBzAPgAoA3AQwBsBXLALhgHJEeYufERLIA-DGTcwWBljIBKVDRjN2WVCjQAiRNoBQ%20wlmAsmZDczIwc3PgIA%20vAEI9DCRHRxKA9D5ggANaGxqbmluYwAJ7c2s7aME7aAMIG%20h50Ub7%20uAAOJviEgmRkIGSGQA)

`'A' extends A ? A : never` ----> means that if literal type `A` extends passed argument (if passed argument is a subtype of 'A') then return passed argument, otherwise - return `never`. Since `never` is unrepresentable, TS gives you an error.

**MORE ADVANCED EXAMPLE**

First of all, you should get rid of `in` operator, because it is not always narrows the type. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382960/typescript-in-operator-type-guard-narrowing-only-as-literal), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69659545/how-can-i-index-into-an-object-type-in-typescript/69659701#69659701).
It is better to use `hasProperty` instead:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

This is generic and type safe function to check whether property exists or not in the object.

Since, you want to check whether any part of union is assignable to desired type we need to know distinguish arguments with union type with single typed argument.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true
```

COnsider this validation utility:

```js
type Validation<Obj> =
    (IsUnion<Obj> extends true
        ? (NumberRecord extends Obj
            ? Obj : never)
        : (Obj extends NumberRecord
            ? Obj : never)
    )
```

If `Obj` is a union, check whether `NumberRecord` extends `Obj`. If yes, it means that some part of the union is assignable to `NumberRecord` and we can return `Obj` (allow the argument). If `Obj` is not a union of types, we are checking whether `Obj` is a subtype of `NumberArgument`. If yes, `Obj` is allowed, otherwise - return `never`. Hence, if argument has type `undefined` - it is disallowed, because it is neither a union with subtype of `NumberRecord` not subtype of `NumberRecord`.

Let's see how it works:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);


type NumberRecord = {
    one: number;
    two: number;
}

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true

type Validation<Obj> =
    (IsUnion<Obj> extends true
        ? (NumberRecord extends Obj
            ? Obj : never)
        : (Obj extends NumberRecord
            ? Obj : never)
    )

const isA = <
    Obj,
    >(value: Validation<Obj>) =>
    typeof value == "object" &&
    hasProperty(value, 'one') &&
    hasProperty(value, 'two') &&
    typeof value.one === "number" &&
    typeof value.two == "number";

/**
 * Ok
 */
isA({}) // should not work

isA({ one: 1, two: 2 }) // should work
isA(foo) // should work
isA({one:1,two:2,three:3}) // ok

/**
 * Errors
 */
isA(undefined) // should not work

declare var foo: undefined | NumberRecord


isA(42) // expected error
isA({one:1, two:'string'}) // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBACwIZQAoCcwAcCm6YCecAvHADwDyARgFYA0cG2cOAHjDhACZRyzoBLCAHMAfAAowtAFxxq9OFkxZZTLAEpgcbXFlSacAb3lwAZHABKOcOi5k1DAK4QA1hDAB3CKJKitO%20WsYADolMBhwglxg5CgKLzU8QmCQJAAbNMlaBjCNAG5gQsJcOAA5RwBbKjwrGy4SOABvf21IHFkISur0Ap04GA8wDq68AoBfQoB6SbgQdBwuARheYTAcXgjEGBgsKGlp2CQQFzAANzwAMzTPFLAKyYBHR3WYAUgoSYBWAAYAZgB2AAsAE5vgAOSYwdBIaAXMDoCoAWmcbwgiOKOHRYERQg46CgQVR6KiOC%20f3%20nwATGCAGwAYh%20AKptOAGLgAFUIKiACpgACSEDxBJAr0gZHZPmILTg4nZLHYnB4cBhRAA-DKXLJ2epfHBTmABPUOjhzugdWwONxeOJxJrDBALng4HydcQfPrDTr1XzdHAICa8FMZnMFksVmsNmAtjs9gcYEcTqarjdwPcni9UR9Pr9gdmwQBGQGQklQOYCLAwREgBDWFw4i6IpDE3A4qCN5FcyCsknOqCc1FkbmSuAAbW5AF15ZalSP%205BeQKhYSxUPJ%20qLukCb6oc8ij2AGrpQ1IUUQSi0SXS8R8vuds-yHwWxUbdC7vp9dXicpVGrWeH1J8rTkWhpXfHR1RMY1TU0MDtFkcQTEApVv26Wp-1A2CINoX1-Wg6VNFAd54CMABBBoyGleQ6GlCRTnSZ5ZEPNJj1Pc8aFEV0-D6DEwAuPV6JwEhSAAIn0IJhLMUxpViRJ8AIcQ6LSZ4GAAcjaFSdVMKS%20hk5QknkxTlLgFSBjADTJOlHi%20MMnBgjaISRM6H90AkrTLJJXj%20KU2zTKEuBhKc7phIKYBJgAKjCrQwrkFwosmYBSPERoxh1aY%20AQMBHDSep3HgQZ0FihKoBIpK4DaWR8wYUzZEpOAUrgNKoAyrL6ny2LErhMBUpmJrMuyuA2qKkrGnKyrqspOgYAQeZ2l%20eq0rAQrwsiuBooAUXQTB8TiobxGcLgcAuIQFm69K%20py8IBvhQqDpANIkHmfj0DgTrZH2w7jvqAAfMoRnQNDbEKXbAUpU62FwEUFhYTb4V2kb-WkSr%20kGaQVP4IRhBU%20aZnBoIobwLbgCAA)

In other words, we just negated all invalid types.
You can see my article about [type negation](https://catchts.com/type-negation) and [type validation](https://catchts.com/validators)

Comment: Ah, i see for some special cases it's possible. But I can't apply this for more complex stuff, see my updates in the last section. But that's interesting nonetheless!

Comment: @VanCoding made an update