# Typescript property type guards on unknown

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I'm trying to type guard an unknown type

```
const foo  = (obj: unknown) => {
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
        if ('foo' in obj && typeof obj.foo === 'string') {
            return obj.foo;
        }
    }
};
```

[But I'm getting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMYF4YAoQCMBWAuGAVzAGswQB3MASlQD4YBvAKGWQEs4MoBPABwCmILthyoUaAOSiBwKJJgAyRTFG0WbTTE4ZJCEAvZhVuJSt6DhJnADp94qdABORgOaT1rLd6cCohJ2NRO0QAbi9vAF8ImGjI8OYgA)

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'object'.

I also tried with is expression does not work:

```
const foo  = (obj: unknown): obj is { foo: 'string' } => {
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
        if ('foo' in obj && typeof obj.foo === 'string') {
            return obj;
        }
    }
    throw new Error();
};
```

Comment: try to cast `obj` to `any` before checking for `foo`

Comment: @RickyMo you mean `(obj: any) => {...` ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `unknown`? `any` would work, but you've specifically mentioned `unknown` so...

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)

Comment: I'm using gts preset, which throws me a warning when using any. And I prefer to type check the code because it's something written by the user

Comment: I tried with the cast @RickyMo it still shows an error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMYF4YAoQCMBWAuGAVzAGswQB3MASlQD4YBvAKGWQEs4MoBPABwCmILthyoUaAOSiBwKJJgAyRTFG0WbTTFCRYWAIYAnVKtwx9EUzllQA3Ky0cu6SQhAL2YGAePKYvQWFvIwA6N3EpaENPAHNJdQdHTUMBKEJDLx8wxHskmABfRILmfPtmIA

Comment: any works but it's not what i want

Comment: So what do you want?

Comment: By `const bar = obj as any`, you can access properties of `obj`. You need it to be `any` to access its properties. You then checked `'foo' in bar && typeof bar.foo === 'string'`, which fullfill your requirement. What else do you want?

Comment: In this case `unknown` doesn't add any additional type safety. You could just: `const foo  = (obj: any) => obj?.foo === 'string' ? obj?.foo : undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to give TypeScript a little help here:

```
type fooObj = object & { foo: unknown };
const foo = (obj: unknown) => {
    if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
        if ('foo' in obj && typeof (obj as fooObj).foo === 'string') {
            return (obj as fooObj).foo;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using this helper:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);
```

in your case. `in` operator works as expected mostly with unions. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67382960/typescript-in-operator-type-guard-narrowing-only-as-literal), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69659545/how-can-i-index-into-an-object-type-in-typescript/69659701#69659701)

Working solution:

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const foo = (obj: unknown) => {
  if (typeof obj === 'object' && obj) {
    if (hasProperty(obj, 'foo') && typeof obj.foo === 'string') {
      return obj.foo;
    }
  }
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwgBQE4gA4FNVQJ4wC8MAPAPIBGAVgDQxqYxYAeUWYAJhDNKgJZgA5gD4AFCGoAuGJVowM6DNIYYAlACgYMaRKow%203WTABkMAEpZQqDiRV0ArmADWYEAHcwwosM0zqlqAA6BRAoULxsQMQIMg8VHHxA4AQAGxTxajoQtQBudXVQSFgAMxAQIhgMqmlHF3cwVW8YAG9fPmLK-GwQDt0iQmIAcl0AwZNTXUbWrS12yuj43DwqukHSkEHG41MurB6YXUD1-qHeAUFNlt8ZmFQsKHtUMAPqI7K8m4BfX2-PnKA)

However, since you want to throw an error if `obj` is invalid, you can use [`assert function`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```js
const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
  : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

function foo(obj: unknown): asserts obj is { foo: string } {
  const isValid =
    typeof obj === 'object' &&
    obj &&
    hasProperty(obj, 'foo') &&
    typeof obj.foo === 'string';

  if (!isValid) {
    throw new Error();
  }

};

declare var obj: unknown;

foo(obj);

obj.foo // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwgBQE4gA4FNVQJ4wC8MAPAPIBGAVgDQxqYxYAeUWYAJhDNKgJZgA5gD4AFCGoAuGJVowM6DNIYYAlACgYMaRKow%203WTABkMAEpZQqDiRV0ArmADWYEAHcwwosM0zqlqAA6BRAoULxsQMQIMg8VHHxA4AQAGxTxajoQtQBudXUAM0dgKD5wGAKQEAyqaUcXdzBVaSQIBO5dfW4Abwqq6V4BQRgAXxhu31BIWAMANVS%20DiJfLXxsEAKYTsIdmAByXQC9k2MVreoTs%20j43Dwauj3KkD3VS61ViKwN86pAp6JdntBkI9nlfHxNqIAIRzBYcV4Td4wKBwdBuGBgLDogCiqHQqFEqjyWhG%20RGYI4lhSCFQWBgADcaT86s5XB4wU8akT8ro-lUYAB6AVbJz5IA)