# Strange object is possibly "null" error in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this simple function that checks if an unknown value looks like a `Date` object:

```
function looksLikeDate(obj: unknown): obj is { year: unknown; month: unknown; day: unknown } {
    return (
        obj !== null && typeof obj === "object" && "year" in obj && "month" in obj && "day" in obj
    );
}
```

But I get the following error for the `"year" in obj` part of the code:

> Object is possibly 'null'. (2531)

When I switch `obj !== null` and `typeof obj === "object"` the error goes away: [TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAGznA1gZwDI3QUwBEBDKfARgAo4AjAKwC5Fx0w4B3MASidrsRiZEAb0QBPfMQBOTFm04BuRAFsEUABaywrDmCUATYmK07OiAL4iAUIluIp+KCClJKNux6hiADvjjBEPkQAXlDEACI+fGhwxAAyOMD6RABCMLAQZGR4xPCJaViYJCCEiNUwDULi5NLwwzEqpLp3Wy4FK3MrK1BIWAQUNCxcAhIyACZqehN5bl5kwRFxSRlmbRmlco1p3QMjbbNLYRb7R2dXY48gtODEDKycxC9ffyaQsMj6aKhY2vypRpKuU26gBNVy9VBzQ8bQ6QA)

Isn't this strange? Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript property type guards on unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69705488/typescript-property-type-guards-on-unknown)

Comment: @captain-yossarian: That doesn't explain that `typeof null` returns `'object'`, which is the problem here.

Comment: Is there a reason your type-guard doesn't ensure that `year`, `month`, and `day` are typed as `number`? If they can be `string`-or-`number` then you should use `day: string | number`.

Comment: @Dai yes, they could be strings.

Comment: This is because `obj !== null` does not narrow the `obj` to the `object` type. After this guard, `obj` is still `unknown`. TS does not support negation types, hence it is impossible to express `unknown | not null`. Whereas, `typeof obj === object` narrows the `obj` to specific union `object | null`. After that you are allowed to extract `null` with another one typeguard

Comment: @captain-yossarian TypeScript _does_ support "negation types" insofar as you can express `object | not(null)` with the `never` type. I think you an also express something equivalent to "`unknown && !null`" though with a different syntax.

Comment: @Dai I know about this workaround. How would you express type: `any number except 3` ?. It is possible to use `never` if you are able to infer this type like here https://catchts.com/type-negation but if you need to express this type literally, without function helper - it would be impossible to write smth like this: `type N = number | not 3`

Comment: @captain-yossarian I believe conditional-types should work for that, e.g.: `type Is3 = 3; type N<V> = V extends Is3 ? never : V;`.

Comment: @Dai you are right, but you should still infer the value. In this case `3`. Maybe I was not clear enough. You can negate with help of extra utility, in other words if you are allowed to infer the type of value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typeof null === 'object'
```

If you do the `typeof` check after the `null` check, the `obj` *can* be null, even though you checked for `null` before, but the TS compiler is a little naïve.

Those type guards are a little fragile in that sense, as in your example, `typeof obj === 'object'` changed the type from *"not null"* to `object | null`

Comment: Yea, it was, @KrisztiánBalla :D

Comment: On that first line? That's intentional. The type of `null` is `'object'`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is not how this should work imho. (A && B) and (B && A) should have the same result.

Comment: Each subsequent type guard changes the type of the value, after it. Those type guards don't take earlier type guards into consideration. `typeof <something> === 'object'` will always result in that something being typed `object | null`, which is why you need the `null` check after it.